# Fill Z3Py Tree with values

Tags: python, z3

I have this tree datatype, where I want to be able to go up and down. But actually, any structure will work, as long as I can get the parent/left child/right child of a node.

```
Tree = Datatype('Tree')
Tree.declare('nil')
Tree.declare('node', ('label', IntSort()), ('left', Tree), ('up', Tree), ('right', Tree))
Tree = Tree.create()
```

But I don't know how to fill the datastructure... I thought I could create the tree one node at a time like the following, but that seems to be the wrong way.

```
trees = [Const('t' + str(i), Tree) for i in range(3)]
Tree.up(trees[0]) = Tree.nil
Tree.left(trees[0]) = trees[1]
Tree.right(trees[0]) = trees[2]
Tree.up(trees[1]) = trees[0]
Tree.up(trees[2]) = trees[0]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling that you are slightly mistaken about how such data structures work. Z3's language, and thus also Z3py's, is the language of first-order logic (modulo theories), in which only assumptions/facts exist. One of the major differences with respect to imperative programming languages is, that you don't have destructive updates*, i.e., you cannot update the value of an entity.

In your code you try to build the data structures in an imperative way by essentially manipulating pointers, e. g., by the (attempted) assignment

```
Tree.up(trees[0]) = Tree.nil
```

What you probably had in mind was "making `trees[0].up` point to `nil`". However, since destructive updates are not part of a first-order language, you instead have to "think functional", i.e., "assume that `up(trees[0]) == nil`". Adding such assumptions can be done as follows ([online](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/QruT5) on rise4fun):

```
s = Solver()

s.add(
  Tree.up(trees[0]) == Tree.nil,
  Tree.left(trees[0]) == trees[1],
  Tree.right(trees[0]) == trees[2],
  Tree.up(trees[1]) == trees[0],
  Tree.up(trees[2]) == trees[0]
)

print s.check() # sat -> your constraints are satisfiable
```

A consequence of not having destructive updates is that you cannot modify your data structure in a way typical for imperative programming languages. With such updates it would be possible to modify the tree such that `trees[1].up.left != trees[1]`, for example, by the assignment `trees[1].up.left = trees[2]` (for `trees[1] != trees[2]`). However, If you add corresponding assumptions

```
s.add(
  trees[1] != trees[2],
  Tree.left(Tree.up(trees[1])) == trees[2]
)

print s.check() # unsat
```

you'll see that your constraints are no longer satisfiable, because the old and new assumptions contradict.

By the way, your definition of the `Tree` datatype makes it possible to assume that `Tree.up(nil) == someTree`. Assuming that `t1 != t2` are leaves of a tree and that `left(t1) == right(t1) == nil` and analogous for `t2`, then you'll have a contradiction if `up(nil) == t1` and `up(nil) == t2`. I don't know how to prevent this on the level of Z3, though.

<sup>* Destructive updates could be added as syntactic sugar because they can be turned into assumptions by a so-called *passification* transformation. This, for example, is done in the intermediate verification language [Boogie](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/boogie/).</sup>

Comment: The main problem is, I think, that I'm not yet clear about the separation of internal Z3 (FirstOrder) and Python. And thanks for the problem you pointed out in my datastructure! Perhaps I should add `up(nil) == left(nil) == right(nil) == nil` as I never want to evaluate `up(nil)` or anything with `nil`

Comment: If you never mention `up(nil)` then you won't gain anything from this assumption. You could use it as a kind of sanity check for debugging purposes, though, because your state would become inconsistent as soon as you `up(nil) == t` for some `t != nil`.